# Volume control slider isn't working on Sony Vaio VGN CS170F

Tags: sound, keyboard, vaio, xev

I have just installed Ubuntu 12.04, I'm taking the big step, the problem is that I am new with Linux systems and I am really having a hard time getting it work with all the options of my Vaio machine.

My problem here is, the volume control slider doesn't work. This is kind of touch pad control that Sony Vaio has in some models. This is how it should work, if you touch/slide it to the right it, turns up the volume, if you touch/slide it left, it turns it down and if you touch the center, it mutes the volume.

I read a lot of posts and tried a couple of things but finally I did this:

I ran 'xev' in the terminal and tried the touch/sliding keys but it didn't give me anything back, not a single line of information.

What does this means? and how can I solve this?

I would really appreciate the help of anyone in this problem

Its a Sony vaio VGN CS170F running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is EOL and OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. VTC this unanswered question as `not reproducible`.